# Incompatible shapes: [30,5] vs. [5,1] [[node huber_loss/Sub ..........]]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, dimension

I am having a simple neural network I would like to train.
It should enable forecasting through a window strategy.

But, I am prompted the following error by first epoch:
Incompatible shapes: [30,5] vs. [5,1]
[[node huber_loss/Sub

I have tried using an "embedding" layer to define the dimension of the output, as mentioned in another post over stack overflow.
Without success.

Here is the code that I re-used from a free-MOOC:

```
def window_dataset(series, window_size, batch_size=32,
                   shuffle_buffer=1000):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(series)
    dataset = dataset.window(window_size + 1, shift=1, drop_remainder=True)
    dataset = dataset.flat_map(lambda window: window.batch(window_size + 1))

    dataset = dataset.map(lambda window: (window[:-1], window[-1]))
    
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size) #.prefetch(1)
    
    return dataset


keras.backend.clear_session()
tf.random.set_seed(42)
np.random.seed(42)

window_size = 30
train_set = window_dataset(x_train, window_size)
valid_set = window_dataset(x_valid, window_size)


model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(5, input_shape=([window_size,5]))
])                                                 

optimiseur = keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-5, momentum=0.9)

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.Huber(), optimizer=optimiseur, metrics=["mae"])

model.fit(train_set, epochs=100, validation_data=valid_set)
```

Here is the shape of elements in `train_set` or `valid_set`:

```
x, y = train_set

x= tf.Tensor(..., shape=(32, 30, 5), dtype=int64)  
y= tf.Tensor(..., shape=(32, 5), dtype=int64)
```

If anyone could, please, help to sort this issue out, I would be glad!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the issue:

following code was changed

```
 dataset = dataset.map(lambda window: (window[:-1], window[-1]))
```

into

```
dataset = dataset.map(lambda window: (window[:-1], tf.reshape(window[-1], [1,5])))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).